# Mysql ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 problem

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

The problem is the bellow query.

```
   SELECT RSV.Value
     FROM tblsubmitedservice SS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ServiceID, Value 
             FROM tblservicevalue  
         ORDER BY RAND() 
            LIMIT 1) RSV ON RSV.ServiceID = SS.ServiceID
```

This query must retrieve 1 random value from tblservicevalue in JOIN with tblsubmitedservice like above.  But sometimes (I do not know why sometimes) the query return `null`.  If I move the "LIMIT 1" to the end of query (no more inside the subquery), the query run correctly.

This query is simplified to understand and in the original query this solution is not possible.

Comment: There's a fundamental misunderstanding in what you posted.  The LEFT JOIN derived table will be executed **once**, not for each `serviceid` value in the `SUBMITEDSERVICE` table.

Comment: Secondly, why would you LEFT JOIN to the source of what you want to return?  The query as-is `NULL` could be returned -- in multiple columns.

Comment: Because this is not the original query(As said). I have another `LEFT JOIN tblservicevalue` that retrieve X kind of submited service value and `LEFT JOIN (SELECT ServiceID, Value...` retrieve only the Y kind in random manner.

Answer (score 0):

May be all the ServiceID's in tblservicevalue don't have corresponding ServiceIDs in tblsubmittedservice i.e., there is not a strict one-to-one relation between the tables.

You can check the tables using this:

1>Check the number of rows of tblservicevalue and tblsubmittedservice are equal.
2>Next check if

```
SELECT
    RSV.Value
FROM tblsubmitedservice SS
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ServiceID, Value FROM tblservicevalue) RSV ON RSV.ServiceID=SS.ServiceID
```

has the same no. of rows as tblservicevalue,tblsubmittedservice.

If either of 1,2 fail, clearly the behaviour is due to the reason I explained above.

Comment: I test this query with correct limited data, so all data has corresponding value in both table. And i don't know why the number of rows of tblservicevalue and tblsubmittedservice should be equal. I should get value from tblservicevalue per submitted service in tblsubmittedservice.

Comment: Please rephrase your comment.I couldn't understand what you wanted to say:(

Answer (score 0):

Check if below query returns any rows:

```
 SELECT RSV.Value
 FROM tblsubmitedservice SS
 LEFT JOIN tblservicevalue RSV ON RSV.ServiceID = SS.ServiceID
 WHERE RSV.ServiceID IS NULL
```

If it does return any rows it means that some rows from tblsubmitedservice have no correspoding rows in tblservicevalue (with regard to ServiceID field). In case of LEFT JOIN if rows on the right side can't be found (ie. there's no such RSV.ServiceID in RSV table) NULLs are used instead.

Contrary to previous comment number of rows does not have to be equal.